# Flash and TTD, testing display objects

Tags: actionscript-3, tdd

Most of the resources I find are from 2010 and do not clearly answer a question I have about test-driven development on Flash. Seeing as it's often used for games and such, I'm wondering how I can setup my tests so that I can make sure a display object behaves properly.

I did do the quick Hello World kind of app from [here](http://fr.slideshare.net/anupom98/introduction-to-tdd-with-flexunit) to learn the basics of TDD, but what about if I have a character in a game where the player can, visually change his armor? How do I test that the armor is properly changed? It's not like my addArmor() function would return anything... For that matter, how would I test if the character's position if the one we expect from the code?

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around the whole visual part of a Flash app and how to properly test it. I'm hoping it's not too silly a question and that I'm not just missing one simple fact or aspect of TDD that would totally answer this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm busy writing a game using TDD and my solution looks as follows. My game is a 2D so I can represent the screen as an array of chars. I pass this array in to my game logic and then I verify  (using unit tests) that the array has been modified correctly.

Once I'm ready to render the screen I only pass the array to the graphics routine. The graphics routine only knows about the array and it substitutes each char with its corresponding graphics tile. I don't bother to unit test the graphics routine because that is pretty hard to do and when you manage it you end up with a pretty fragile test. Instead I try to make the graphics routine as simple as possible. In this case it is literally "Pull-char-from-array-map-it-to-a-tile-draw-tile".

The underlying principle is something that I think of as my TDD-enlightenment moment when I realized it. You should use unit tests to verify that your code is calling the code from your libraries and your environment/framework correctly (and also that one of your modules is calling another module correctly). This is exactly what mock/fake objects are designed to do. From a unit testing perspective you don't really care if the drawTile() or writeFile() or sendUdpPacket() function actually draws a tile or writes a file or sends a packet. You can establish how these methods need to be called using conventional (non-TDD/unit test) test code and then your TDD work verifies that you make the necessary calls correctly.

In your case, when the character dons armor, it is probably represented in a data-structure somewhere. This is what you should verify using TDD. Your graphics can then be composed from your data structures. Once you've visually verified that the character is now drawn with armor on it is unlikely that this will change, provided all your data level calls are TDD'd.

My favourite quote in this context:

> You can write it simple, then there is obviously nothing wrong, or
>   complicated, then there is nothing obviously wrong.

MTFBWY